# xmlhttp.send() within .each() sends only the last record

Tags: jquery, ajax, each, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to teach myself some php and Ajax for a pet startup project - no $$$ to hire a real tech guy. :-)
Anyway, this is the background. 
I have a data selected in a HTML table that when submitted is called into a update function.
I loop through the table to pick the selected records (radio button) and assign them to $row and loop through each element to call an update php file and send the records to get added to the database. 
When I have the javascript alert statement all the records gets added to the database. But if I comment out the alert then only the last record gets added. 
I tried to add 3 second, 5 second delay in the loop still no use.

here is the code snippet - some of the variables are set outside this loop and there is no issue with the values.

```
$row.each(function() {
```

var $rowcells = $(this).find('td'); //entire row split into columns
                            var name = $rowcells.eq(0).text();   //name of the person selected
                            relationtype = $rowcells.eq(1).children().val(); // relationship with the person


                            //alert("I was here with "+name); // all records get added when this alert is uncommented
                            xmlhttp.open("POST","profileupdate.php",true);
                            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                            xmlhttp.send("type="+type+"&userid="+userid+"&userrelid="+userrelid+"&relationtype="+relationtype+"&timeline="+timeidtext);

                        });

I understand adding one at a time like this will be costly on db performance. I should change that logic anyways. But, in the interim would love to know what goes on here.n

Comment: try to recreate the xmlhttp object every iteration: `xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();`

Comment: You are using an asynchronous request which is essentially flooding the server with requests.  Change this line: xmlhttp.open("POST","profileupdate.php",true); to xmlhttp.open("POST","profileupdate.php",false); to make it synchrounous instead.  Only one request will be sent at a time and the next request will be sent once the previous one has finished.

Comment: thank you! false parameter works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending HTTP request to the server asynchronously (the 'true' second parameter to xmlhttp.open). This means that the next item in the row overrides the previous one.

You can try:

- using multiple xmlhttp objects (one for each element of the array)
- using 'false' as the second parameter
- only processing the next element after the previous one completes (in 'onreadystatechange' handler)

In the third case, you can't use the 'each' iterator.

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: I used parameter as 'false' and it works. Thanks everyone! I appreciate your help.

Comment: btw, I sometimes refer to w3schools, but many in this forum has bashed that. is that not a reliable one?